# Please review my config. My vimdiff not working with GIT after setup

Tags: git, vimdiff

I used the commands following commands in order to make vimdiff my default diff tool under git.

```
# git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
# git config --global difftool.prompt false
# git config --global alias.diff difftool
```

My git config file looks like the below when I type

```
# git config -l

diff.tool=vimdiff
merge.tool=vimdiff
difftool.prompt=false
alias.diff=difftool
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

When I run `git diff` it still uses the less method and displays my diff in line instead of using the vimdiff program. What am I missing in my config that prevents git from using vimdiff?

Comment: If I use the command `git difftool master` it works just fine. Only when I try to use the alias of diff does it no longer work as expected.

Comment: Can you remove the git alias, just to check if that work better?

Comment: @Roman Thanks. I really wanted to use Git Diff for vimdiff but it looks like that will be impossible. I will create an alias for another word and use that. Turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man git-config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide
>   existing Git commands are ignored.

`diff` is an existing git command, so your alias is ignored.